# Protecting php files with password

Tags: php

The hosting I am using allows protecting files with username and password. Will it "break" something if I put password on a file that is included or required in many php pages of my site?

Comment: I'm assuming this is `.htpasswd` (http basic auth) protection - in which case no... but do you really need to allow access to an include file over http at all?

Comment: @FastTurtle I don't think that is the password protection the OP is talking about.  I believe CD001 is on the right track that this is simply HTTP authentication.

Comment: basicaly when I open locked page, alert pops-up with fields for username and password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is HTTP authentication, this provides no password protection on the filesystem so including files from the filesystem will not be affected.  This also does not prevent files from being read from the filesystem by other users if they have the permissions to do so.

This will only display a password prompt to users who access the file path from the web server (http://)

If you actually have private files that you wish only to be included from your PHP script, then you can keep them out of the public_html (or web server root directory) completely.

for example:

- app/private.php
- public_html/index.php

Inside index.php:

```
<?php
include "../app/private.php";
/* Other code */
?>
```

As app is outside the public_html directory, it will not be able to be served by the web server, but you can still include it from the filesystem.

Comment: Just a footnote: If you've got a weird host that doesn't allow you to create files outside the docroot (used to happen with some shared hosts back in the day - might still for all I know) you can also prevent *include* directories from being read over HTTP by using an `.htaccess` file containing just `Deny from all`